# What is your C# code doing within a Xamrin build?

Tags: xamarin

I've read through a lot of documentation on Xamarin and my understanding is that it exposes the native APIs on each platform via C# and .NET, and this way, offers a sort of one-to-one binding. The native build produced contains some of the applicable .NET libraries (based on linker optimisation).

However, I can't seem to find any information about what actually happens within the native build itself.

Assuming my understanding is correct, my question is:
Within the native build, does the code you've written call the native API functions via a call to native .NET functions included in the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, it calls native API's through .NET code that runs on Mono, via the binding concept you already seem to be familiar with.

Xamarin uses these bindings to call the native code from your C# code. There are a few differences depending on the platform you are running on.

**iOS**

Your IPA-file will contain 2 things:

- The executable of your .NET code (AOT-compiled), which is run through the Mono runtime
- Native libraries, which use the objective-C runtime. The .NET code calls these libraries/API's via bindings.

Both the Mono runtime and the Objective-C runtime are running on top of a UNIX-like kernel.

Take a look at [this Xamarin iOS architecture documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/architecture/) for a more extensive explanation.

**Android**

Android is a little more complex to understand and explain. This is because some of the API's are only exposed through the Android Runtime API.

The bindings in Android are working through concepts such as:

- "Android Callable Wrappers" (Android Runtime to Mono)
- "Managed Callable Wrappers" (Bindings to Android Runtime API's)

[The Xamarin Android architecture documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) explains these concepts and inner workings in great detail.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a lot of things for me. I read through the documentation you linked to. The ACWs and MCWs for Android are certainly make the Android architecture seem more complex than iOS. Question: By the 'mono' runtime, are you referring to MonoTouch? And is mono embeded in your app during the Xamarin build process?

Comment: MonoTouch is actually the old naming for Xamarin iOS. Mono is included in your IPA or APK-file, together with the required Base Class Libraries for .NET. It's stripped down to the bare minimum after linking though. See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/#Release_Packages